# ListDensityPlot using

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two data tables with identical parts along the vertical axis.
For example:

```
Tab1 = Table[i*10, {i, 0, 20}];

Tab2 = Table[i, {i, 0, 20}];

Tab3 = Table[i*0.1, {i, 0, 20}];
```

Now I want to combine both graphics on one:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{Tab1, Tab3}], 
Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
FrameLabel -> {"Parameter 1", "Y axis", None, None},
ImagePadding -> 50, FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}}];

plot2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{Tab2, Tab3}], 
Frame -> {False, False, True, True},
FrameLabel -> {None, None, "Parameter 2", "Y axis"},
ImagePadding -> 50, FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}];

Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

And the result is:
[image]

Now I want to use ListDensityPlot to show how Yaxis depends from Parameter 1 and 2. In order to do this, I need the abscissa axis to be parameter 1, and on the ordinate axis there was parameter 2.

UPD: I found a way to do it:

```
tab1 = Table[i*10, {i, 0, 20}];(*Parameter 1*)

tab2 = Table[i, {i, 0, 20}];(*Parameter 2*)

tab3 = Table[i*0.1, {i, 0, 20}];

tab4 = Transpose[{tab1, tab2, tab3}];

ListDensityPlot[tab4, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic,
Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {"Parameter 1", "Parameter 2"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], ImageSize -> Large]
```

As result I have a white graph
[image]
I find solution of this problem use:

> DataRange -> All

And the result is
[image]
How we can see that the abscissa axis has another values. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that `ListDensityPlot` isn't behaving well because you only provide values along the diagonal. If you provide values for points evenly spread out in the space, it will probably behave as you expect.